# How to send data to servlet and retrieve data from servlet using backbone.js

Tags: servlets, backbone.js, communication

I'm trying to send some data to servlet using backbone js and i want to  retrieve  that data to backbone.js view. Here i mentioned my model and collection code. Please help me.

```
ContactManager.Models.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: null,
    tel: null,
    email: null,
    address:null,
    avatar: null
  },
  url: "/servlet1",
  initialize: function() {
    this.set('avatar','phone.png');
  },
});

ContactManager.Collections.Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: ContactManager.Models.Contact 
});
```

Comment: What data does `/servlet1` return for a GET request?

Comment: name, tel, email, address-- these 4 datas i want to send to servlet1 and want to collect that datas from servlet. I dont know how to send these data to servlet.

Comment: Just save the model instance?

Comment: Not clear.. Can you please explain. Because I'm a beginner

Comment: How to save the model  data and how to collect that data from servlet?

Comment: Please read the documentation or some tutorials/books and understand basic concepts before asking questions in SO